# How does Tayam, Luminous Enigma interact with Phyrexian Altar?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have three creatures that each have a vigilance counter on them, can I activate [Tayam, Luminous Enigma](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tayam%2C%20Luminous%20Enigma) by removing their vigilance counters and sacrificing them to [Phyrexian Altar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Phyrexian%20Altar)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 601.2f The player determines the total cost of the spell. Usually this is just the mana cost. Some spells have additional or alternative costs.
> ...

> 601.2g If the total cost includes a mana payment, the player then has a chance to activate mana abilities (see rule 605, “Mana Abilities”). Mana abilities must be activated before costs are paid.

That means you have to activate Phyrexian Altar *before* paying the costs, and removing the counters is part of the costs. So what you propose won't work.

Comment: I'd note that you can sacrifice a creature in response to his ability being put onto the stack, then return them back onto the battlefield when his ability resolves, however.